# How to increase PHP memory limit for Symfony project under Windows?

Tags: php, caching, composer-php, out-of-memory, symfony

I have a Symfony3 project on my localhost (Windows 7 Entreprise) and I use Wamp Server 3.0.0 with PHP 5.6.16 and Apache 2.4.17.

When I do : `php bin/console cache:clear`

I have this error :
[image]

I also have a memory limit error **every time I use Composer** (for installing bundles for example).

I modified my **php.ini** : `memory_limit = 1G` and **restarted all services** of Wamp.

I still have this problem. My project is a big one so maybe it comes from it.

The only solution that I found is to increase memory limit in every command line (-1 = unlimited) :/

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 C:\Path\of\composer.phar require ...
```

In production, my project is on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

Have you a better way to increase memory limit for my entire project ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file? You can check which `.ini` files are used by running `php --ini` make sure that none of the additional `.ini` files is overwriting your `memory_limit`. You can check it with `php -i` (and search for `memory_limit`) or if bash and grep is available (eg. git bash) try `php -i | grep memory_limit` to see if your `memory_limit` is set correctly.

Comment: You say you have set your memory limit to 1G, but your error says the allowed size is about 134MB. @Peh is probably right: you did not, in fact, change the right memory limit.

Comment: @Peh I did `php --ini` and here is the result : `Loaded Configuration File : C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\php.ini`. So the good file is obviously used. Going to check if this file has my 1G limit or not and ... it has a 128M limit !! Actually, using Wamp context menu, I modified `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini` even if I clicked on PHP folder > php.ini (in the menu).

Comment: @Peh : So, in the php.ini of PHP, I replace 128M by 500M, I think it's enough... Thank you !! The Wamp menu is very done poorly...

Answer (score 0):

Try  set

```
@ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
```

Run

```
php -i|grep php.ini
```

To find where  php.ini and echo phpinfo() after setting .

Unset the variables after using and optimize your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, maybe my case will be helpful for someone.

Check php version you are using as php cli by typing **php -v** in command prompt. Then check php version your web-server is using - create php file

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and run it on your server. In case the versions are different, you have to follow such route on windows:

```
Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced system settings->Environment Variables
```

Below **System Variables** table you should see **Path** variable. The php version mentioned in the path is used as php cli. Change the route to the php version your server is using (where you modified memory_limit).
Then you have to **close** all your active command prompt windows for changes to be made.